# My aiosqlite Python database wont update the second table when I try

Tags: python, sqlite, nextcord, aiosqlite

I have a aiosqlite Python database for a discord bot using Nextcord.
I have one table that works fine but the second one just wont update or maybe even create (I'm not sure). I'm wondering if it being in a class for a Nextcord cog is something to do with the issue.

I tried almost everything I could think of even using chatGPT. I Have no idea why its like this and don't use SQL DS's enough to know why. I have been trying to fix this for over 3 months so any help would be appreciated.

The code is here:

```
async def create_tables(self):
        if self.db is not None:
            await self.db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS econ (spin_tokens INTEGER, tokens INTEGER, slash_cmds INTEGER, status INTEGER, dank INTEGER, user INTEGER)')
            await self.db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS daily (daily_claim INTEGER, daily_claimed_stamp INTEGER, daily_streak INTEGER, user INTEGER)')

    async def commit(self):
        await self.connect.commit()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.bot.db = await aiosqlite.connect("econ.db")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await self.create_tables()
        await self.bot.db.commit()
        print("DB ready...")
        print("-----------")`
```

```
async def get_dval(self, user):
        async with self.bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
            await cursor.execute("SELECT daily_claim, daily_claimed_stamp, daily_streak FROM daily WHERE user = ?", (user.id,))
            data = await cursor.fetchone()
            print(data)
            if data is None:
                await self.daily_make(user)
                return 0, 0, 1, 0
            (daily_claim, daily_claimed_stamp, daily_streak) = data[0], data[1], data[2]
            return daily_claim, daily_claimed_stamp, daily_streak

async def dclaimed_update(self, user, mode="daily_claim"):
        now = datetime.now()
        now_time = now.strftime("%H.%M")
        print(now_time)

        if self.db is not None:
            await self.db.execute(f'''UPDATE daily SET daily_claim = now_time WHERE user = (user.id)''')
            await self.db.commit()
```

```
@nextcord.slash_command(description="adds to bal")
    async def daily(self, interaction : Interaction):
        now = datetime.now()
        now_time = now.strftime("%H.%M")
        print(now_time)
        daily_claim, daily_claimed_stamp, daily_streak = await self.get_dval(interaction.user)


        if daily_claim == 0:
            resK = await self.dclaimed_update(interaction.user)
            daily_claim, daily_claimed_stamp, daily_streak = await self.get_dval(interaction.user)
            await interaction.send("Sugg")
        else:
            await interaction.send("No")
```

Comment: You can check if the table exists by connecting to your database file with either the sqlite3 command line client or Python's [sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) and doing `SELECT * FROM daily` (assuming `daily` is the table in question).

Comment: @snakecharmerb I Think it is being created as I can read the values with daily_claim, daily_claimed_stamp, daily_streak = await self.get_dval(interaction.user)